# Dynamic chaptername wrong in tableofcontents

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, counters

I want to print my appendix-titles with the prefix "Appendix A: [some title]" , "Appendix B: [some other title]" ... .

I used the following defined commands (runnable tex-document at the end):

```
\newcounter{rsss}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\appendixString}{
    \setcounter{rsss}{\value{chapter}}
    \addtocounter{rsss}{- \value{chapterCounter}}
    Appendix\Alph{rsss} :
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\appendixStringHeadline}{
    \setcounter{rsss}{\value{chapter}}
    \addtocounter{rsss}{- \value{chapterCounter}}
    \addtocounter{rsss}{1}
    Appendix \Alph{rsss} :
}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\appendix}[2]{
    \addchap[\appendixStringHeadline #1]{\appendixStringHeadline     #1}\label{#2}
    \ihead{
    \appendixString #1
    }
    \stepcounter{chapter}
}
```

This works for the Title and the headline, but in the tableofcontents, there is always "Appendix A". How can i fix this?
I tried to set the tableofcontents-name manually with `[]`, but this didn't 
work :/.
Thank you for helping :)

Runnable tex-file

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{scrpage2}\pagestyle{scrheadings}


\newcounter{chapterCounter}
\newcounter{rsss}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\appendixString}{
    \setcounter{rsss}{\value{chapter}}
    \addtocounter{rsss}{- \value{chapterCounter}}
    Appendix \Alph{rsss} :
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\appendixStringHeadline}{
    \setcounter{rsss}{\value{chapter}}
    \addtocounter{rsss}{- \value{chapterCounter}}
    \addtocounter{rsss}{1}
    Appendix \Alph{rsss} :
}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\appendix}[2]{
    \addchap[\appendixStringHeadline #1]{\appendixStringHeadline     #1}\label{#2}
    \ihead{
        \appendixString #1
    }
    \stepcounter{chapter}
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{ Bla}
\chapter{ Bla Bla}
\appendix{test 1}{bla bla}
\appendix{test 2}{bla}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't set the counters inside the argument of \addchap.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{scrpage2}\pagestyle{scrheadings}


\newcounter{chapterCounter}
\newcounter{rsss}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\appendix}[2]{%
    \clearpage
    \setcounter{rsss}{\value{chapter}}%
    \addtocounter{rsss}{- \value{chapterCounter}}%
    \addtocounter{rsss}{1}%
    \addchap[Anhang \Alph{rsss} : #1]{Anhang \Alph{rsss} :     #1}\label{#2}
    \ihead{%
        Appendix \Alph{rsss} : #1
    }%
    \stepcounter{chapter}
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{ Bla}
\chapter{ Bla Bla}
\appendix{test 1}{bla bla}
\appendix{test 2}{bla}

\end{document}
```

(I don't understand why you are using all this additional counters and why you don't use the chapter prefixes offered by KOMA-script, and why you use "Anhang" in the text, but "Appendix" in the header but didn't change this part of your code.)

Comment: Sorry, I missed to translate "Anhang" (german) into Appendix. Fixed :)

Comment: With this solution, the number of the head and the number of the chapter gets out of sync

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the `\clearpage` (but imho all the counters are unnecessary, but as I didn't understand what you are after ...).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're using such a complicated approach.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{scrpage2}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\newcommand{\appendixString}{Appendix \thechapter: }

\newcommand{\addappendix}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{chapter}
  \addchap{\appendixString #1}%
  \ihead{\appendixString #1}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Bla}
\chapter{Bla Bla}

\appendix

\addappendix{test 1}\label{bla bla}
\addappendix{test 2}\label{bla}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Redefining `\appendix` is not the best choice in any case.